# Why setting flex display for a table column breaks the table structure?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

If the 2nd and 3rd column is set to be a flex element in a 3 columned table then the table structure breaks and the 3rd column slips below the 2nd loosing the table like structure. Why this happens?

```css
table {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: red;
}

.first {
  width: 100px;
}

.second {
  display:flex;
  background-color:blue;
}

.third {
  display:flex;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="first">asdad<td>
    <td class="second"> asdasd</td>
    <td class="third"> asdads</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I'd expect that I get 3 columns and I can put flex items in them.

Comment: Why are you mixing display types and overriding the default type? It's not necessary

Comment: Instead of applying flex property directly on column, create div inside that column and apply flex property on that.

Comment: I thought that td has some not overrulable behaviour and keeps its semantics whatever I do with it. But I think I need to look at it like a named element that is defaulted with table related display properties which though can be overridden and change the semantic meaning of td.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your changing the behavior of display:table-cell to display:flex, due to this 2 columns are merging into single. You can use below code snippet

```
<table><tr><td class="first">asdad<td><td class="second"><div>asdasd</div></td><td class="third"><div>asdads</div></td></tr></table>


.second > div {display:flex; background-color:blue;}
.third  > div{display:flex;background-color: green;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ulric_469/jtxckL8p/3/